# read data from xls file then update to dbf file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xls, dbf

i want to ask is it possible to read the data in *xls file then get data and update to *.dbf file based on the staff id using vb.net script? if yes, do i need convert the xls to dbf first and then do the update or can just read the xls and update to dbf file without converting?

Answer (score 0):

You can just read the xls file using COM and then update the database using the data you read in from Excel, no need to convert anything.

Saying that it might be simpler to convert the excel data to an access database and just use queries to update the data from there. It depends how complex your data is and how often you have to do this task.

By the way, VB.NET is not a scripting language, it is a pre-compiled language. I assume that by saying "script" you are thinking of vba? What you are trying to do could just as well be done in vba though...

UPDATE:

Here are some details on how I think you should proceed with this. You can google all the stuff required for each step.

Reading in the data from Excel:

If you can you should really avoid yourself a whole load of work and export the data to a csv format file, and read it using a `StreamReader`.
If you really need to read it in straight from Excel, you need to go the COM automation route and you should have a look at using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace. It is very similar to automating Excel via vba, so if you are familiar with that it should be relatively easy.

Writing the data to your database:

This part is quite simple. Use the `System.Data.OleDB` namespace to create a connection to your database and then generate an `OleDBCommand` with the correct query to insert your data and hey presto your're done. If you have a complex database and want to manipulate a lot of data you should really have a look into adapting the `LinqToSQL` framework to work with access or into how to use the `IQToolkit`.

I hope this helps.

UPDATE 2:

Just remembered that I wrote a method to write data to Excel a couple of weeks ago. It's not the same as reading data in, but it should be very similar... In fact reading data should be even simpler. See if this helps you get started:

You need to import `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` for this to work

```
Private Function ExportToExcelFile(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean

    With New Excel.Application
        With .Workbooks.Add()
            For Each sheet As Worksheet In .Worksheets
                If sheet.Index > 1 Then
                    Call sheet.Delete()
                End If
            Next
            With CType(.Worksheets(1), Worksheet).Range("A1")
                ' Do stuff with the cells in you spreadsheet here
            End With
            Call .SaveAs(FileName)
        End With
        Call .Quit()
    End With

End Function
```

For writing stuff to your database [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425851/how-to-save-in-arraylist-string-separated-by-comma/15426338#15426338) which I provided to somebody else recently.

Comment: oic..can u show me the example of update the database in dbf using the data in excel....i've been search in the web...but i only found the converter..pls help me...

Comment: Sorry, but that would involve quite a lot of code, and I can't spend the time to actually write all that just to provide an example for you. But I will add some details on how I think you should proceed.